# No sound in Ubuntu MATE 15.04

Tags: sound, 15.04, mate

No sound in my desktop Ubuntu MATE after new install. When I hit alsamixer I see my headphone is disabled and I have to enable it each time with right key, M then up key.

Couldn't find a satisfactory answer to this problem so I found the solution myself. Couldn't post it as a comment to any of the numerous questions users have regarding this issue because I don't have 50 reputation (...).

So here's the solution, please let me know if you find it useful:

1. save the following two lines in a file called for example /usr/bin/amixer_script.sh

/usr/bin/amixer -c 0 cset iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Volume' 100%
/usr/bin/amixer -c 0 cset iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Switch' 1+ toggle

2. make it executable with sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/amixer_script.sh
3. add /usr/bin/amixer_script.sh to System->Control Center->Startup Applications

There. Your script is launched at each bootup and you have sound.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please use the answer field below to post the solution of your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

1. save the following two lines in a file called for example /usr/bin/amixer_script.sh

/usr/bin/amixer -c 0 cset iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Volume' 100% /usr/bin/amixer -c 0 cset iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Switch' 1+ toggle

2. make it executable with sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/amixer_script.sh
3. add /usr/bin/amixer_script.sh to System->Control Center->Startup Applications

There. Your script is launched at each bootup and you have sound.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution : when alsamixer configuration is ok, run
`sudo alsactl store 0`

It will save your settings once for all.

"0" is for first soundcard , replace with "1" for saving second soundcard state .